Nested OAS 3.0 $refs results in Incorrect type. Expected "object". Error
Example of SwaggerHub for VS Code by Smartbear, error
It seems logical to want to do this...I have all of the "vehicle" attribute schemas declared as the appropriate types above.  I want to use this approach because we use a "prefer=[simple, detail]" request header to define simple view vs. detailed views in the response payload.
What am I missing?
Regards,
Doc
I have a pretty extensive definintion of schema elements for /vehicle.  Our design standards state that we need to make GET queries, return a "simple" set of resource URLs, with basic metadata to qualify the resource item provided.  For the "details" (a GET /vehicles/{resourceID}, we return the details of the /vehicle resource.  All of simple is included in the detailed schema, it's just reduced until the consumer can pick a specific /vehicle to retrieve the detail on.
